# How to use FLATTEN for one level in Pig?

Tags: tuples, apache-pig, bag

## Problem

I have an inner bag comprised of nested tuples that are unnecessary for my expected schema. I'd like to remove one of the tuple layers so that I'm left with just a simple inner bag. I'm using Pig 0.14.

## Example

A sample of my input data.

```
((1,100,0),(2))
((1,100,1),(3,500,60))
```

My desired output.

```
(100,{(2),(3,500,60)})
```

My current state after some minor manipulation (see below), which prompted the question above.

```
(100,{((2)),((3,500,60))})
```

## Attempts

I feel like my complication is that I'm attempting to group on an item inside a tuple. I did a simple group statement, which appears to leave the grouped elements in the tuple (I'm fairly new to Pig).

```
a = LOAD 'data' as (key:tuple(), data:tuple());
b = GROUP a BY key.$1;
c = FOREACH b GENERATE group as vid, b.data as data;
```

Dumping `c` provides the undesired output above. The multi-part key `(a,b,c)` needs to be stripped such that `a` is removed, `b` is used as a group, and `c` can either be removed or not, but only after it is used to create the inner bag.

Attempting to `FLATTEN` ungroups the elements. I can then `FLATTEN` again and re-group, but this seems a little ridiculous. Is there a better way than this?

```
d = FOREACH c GENERATE vid, FLATTEN(data) as data;
e = FOREACH d GENERATE vid, FLATTEN(data);
f = GROUP e BY $0;
```

This still doesn't really provide what I want, since it keeps the key around:

```
(100,{(100,2),(100,3,500,60)})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. This will help a bit.. but this is not a effective solution . lets wait some good brains to post their answers.

Input :

```
 (1,100,0)|(2)
 (1,100,1)|(3,500,60)
```

Pig Script :

```
 records = LOAD '/home/user/bags.txt'  USING PigStorage('|')  AS(key:tuple(),value:tuple());

 records_each = FOREACH records GENERATE key.$1 as grouping_key, flatten(value);

 records_grp = GROUP records_each BY $0;

 records_nested_each = FOREACH records_grp

                      {
                        inner_each=   FOREACH records_each GENERATE $1..;

                         GENERATE group, inner_each;

                     };

 dump records_nested_each;
```

Output :

```
  (100,{(2),(3,500,60)})
```

Comment: Interesting. I think the block is likely the thing I was missing, and this is certainly functional.